# moodle paypal - send paid amount to included page after purchase

Tags: php, paypal, moodle

I'm trying to include an affiliate sales-pixel into the "enrol/paypal/return.php" in the moodle paypal plugin. I need to track the sale to pay out affiliates.

I've included it in the "return.php"with

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/checkout-tag.html');
```

The sales-pixel looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ad.zanox.com/pps/?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxmode=[[1]]
  &CustomerID=[[<?php echo $USER->username ?>]]
  &OrderID=[[<?php echo $USER->username ?>]]
  &CurrencySymbol=[[EUR]]
  &TotalPrice=[[<?php echo $cost ?>]]">
</script>
```

The username and the currency symbol get transmitted fine. But the TotalPrice transmits no value.

Can anyone help me to read out the paid amount and transmit it through the pixel?

Comment: you getting Order ID? i see you put same variable of CustomerID in Order ID

Comment: This is on purpose, we are only selling one course. Handling of the sales is easiest if I get the username twice here.

Comment: then in my opinion its bad approach, lets say yesterday you sale to John Doe and today a different user with same name John Doe tyring to place an order, from your end it will go through but paypal will reject it, to paypal  for every order or sale OrderId must be unique.

Comment: You are right. I changed that.